# Showing a message box in X11 under any circumstances

Tags: c++, linux, x11

I want to make a program that will run in any (or at least most of) X11 based GUI systems, no matter if it is KDE, Gnome, Xfce, etc.
So, I concluded I have to write it using only X11 functions. Unfortunately I found out X11 doesn't support UTF-8 encoding.

All I want now is to somehow display to the end user a message box when my program crashes and there is no way to use any higher level GUI system.

I heard about some console applications like "zenity" and "kdialog". However I can't use them because
I've no guarantee any of them will be available (my distro, for one, has got no such software installed by default)

Comment: "X11 doesn't support UTF-8 encoding."  Is not true.

Comment: You might be surprised to learn that a program that uses, say, GTK, will run perfectly fine on KDE or XFCE desktops. It's your Linux distribution's package manager's job to make sure that all dependencies are properly installed, and you don't have to worry about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to your problem.

Either via

`Xutf8DrawString` (see [here](https://www.unix.com/man-page/xfree86/3x11/xutf8drawstring/) or [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xutf8drawtext))

or if by any chance the macro `X_HAVE_UTF8_STRING` is not present, then you have to convert the multibyte sequence into a two byte sequence (example can be found [here](http://xopendisplay.hilltopia.ca/2009/Mar/Xlib-tutorial-part-8----a-different-way-to-reach-wide-characters.html)) and draw the string with [XDrawText16](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#XDrawText16) or [XDrawString16](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#XDrawString16).

**See also:** [Core Font subsystem](https://www.x.org/wiki/guide/fonts#corefontsubsystem)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Ultimately I found out about Xft extension, but your answer set me on the right track to a successful code.

Answer (score 0):

try
https://github.com/Eleobert/MessageBox-X11
This is a lightweight message box project, using only X11 for rendering, which is very useful if you want to avoid external dependencies on your projects. The function is designed to give you flexibility. And you can easily customize the output by changing the source code.

Comment: I found that too, but this project uses `wchar`s. And my application has got normal `char`s

Comment: @Felix.leg If you don't know how to convert a `char` string to a `wchar_t` string, you probably should learn how to do that.